# SaS: How to calculate moving average in sas using current observation?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am trying to calculate moving average for test data set in SaS, where i want to consider the current calculated moving average for next moving average. I have added the below sample calculation.

I have data something like this

```
 data have;
    input category week value ;
    datalines;
    a 1  10       
    a 2  5          
    a 3           
    a 4  30         
    a 5  50  
    b 1  30      
    b 2  5          
    b 3           
    b 4  0           
    b 5  50
```

;

I want to calculate 4 weeks of moving average at category level

here is below expected output

```
 data want;
       input category  week value moving_average;
   datalines;
    a 1  10  .     
    a 2  5   .       
    a 3  .   .       
    a 4  30  .       
    a 5  50  .      
    a 6  .   28.33
    a 7  .   36.11
    a 8  .   34.86
    b 1  30  .    
    b 2  5   .      
    b 3  .   .     
    b 4  0   .       
    b 5  50  .
    b 6  .   18.33
    b 7  .   22.77
    b 8  .   22.775
    b 9  .   28.46
```

SO here is logic for b

`**For Week 6: (50+0+5)/3 = 18.33
For Week 7: (18.33+50+0)/3 = 22.77
For Week 8: (22.77+18.33+50+0)/4 = 22.775**

Similar calculation can be done for **b**
**One can consider till week 5 is training data after week its test data **
Hope this time i have made clear my problem statement.`

Comment: Do you always have all observations?  For example the WEEK=3 observations with the missing values will always be there so you can just ignore WEEK value and use the previous 4 observations.

Comment: no this will be at random, i have just taken one example.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create new observations? You will need an explicit OUTPUT statement.

You can use a "circular array" to make it easier to calculate the average.

```
data have;
  input category $ week value ;
datalines;
a 1  10       
a 2  5          
a 3  .         
a 4  30         
a 5  50  
b 1  30      
b 2  5          
b 3  .         
b 4  0           
b 5  50         
;

data want;
  set have;
  by category ;
  array c_array [0:3] _temporary_ ;
  if first.category then call missing(of c_array[*]);
  if week <= 5 then c_array[mod(week,4)]=value;
  output;
  if week=5 then do week=6 to 9;
    value=.;
    average=mean(of c_array[*]);
    output;
    c_array[mod(week,4)]=average;
  end;
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    category    week    value    average

  1       a          1       10       .
  2       a          2        5       .
  3       a          3        .       .
  4       a          4       30       .
  5       a          5       50       .
  6       a          6        .     28.3333
  7       a          7        .     36.1111
  8       a          8        .     36.1111
  9       a          9        .     37.6389
 10       b          1       30       .
 11       b          2        5       .
 12       b          3        .       .
 13       b          4        0       .
 14       b          5       50       .
 15       b          6        .     18.3333
 16       b          7        .     22.7778
 17       b          8        .     22.7778
 18       b          9        .     28.4722
```